# Scrapy skipping urls

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using a set of urls that i scraped earlier and using scrapy to loop over it and send it to another function which will iterate through all the pages corresponding to that link and scrape amazon reviews till there is a next button present, but it is skipping many URLs from the start_requests function. Here is the code

````
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request
import logging
import json
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import pandas as pd
from nordvpn_switcher import initialize_VPN,rotate_VPN,terminate_VPN



class AmazonrSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'amazonr'
    allowed_domains = ['*']
    start_urls = ['http://amazon.com/']
    df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Amazon Reviews scraper(part1)\Scraper\reviewsScraper\cleanedProducts.csv')
    link_asin = list(zip(df.SeeAllReviews,df.asin))[:1000]
    counter = 0
    settings = initialize_VPN(save=1,area_input=['complete rotation'])
    rotate_VPN(settings)

    def start_requests(self):
        for pair in self.link_asin: """these URLs are being skipped"""
            request = Request(pair[0],callback=self.parseReview,dont_filter=True, meta={'item': pair[1]})
            yield request

    def parseReview(self, response):
        asin = response.meta['item']

        reviewTitle = response.xpath('//*[@class="a-section a-spacing-none review-views celwidget"]//*[@data-hook="review-title"]//text()').extract()
        reviewTitle = [i.strip() for i in reviewTitle if i.strip() != '' ]
        reviewRatings = response.xpath('//*[@class="a-section a-spacing-none review-views celwidget"]//*[@data-hook="review-star-rating"]//text()').extract()
        
        reviewText = response.xpath('//*[@class="a-section a-spacing-none review-views celwidget"]//*[@data-hook="review-body"]//text()').extract()
        reviewText = [i.strip() for i in reviewText if i.strip() != '']
        reviewDate = response.xpath('//*[@data-hook="review-date"]/text()').extract()

        all_v = list(zip(reviewTitle,reviewText,reviewRatings,reviewDate))
        for i in all_v:
            rtitle = i[0]
            rtext = i[1]
            rrating = i[2]
            rdate = i[3]
            dict_ = {"asin":asin, "reviewTitle":rtitle,"reviewText":rtext,"reviewRatings":rrating,"reviewDate":rdate}
            with open("Reviews.json","a") as fl:
                json.dump(dict_,fl)
                fl.write('\n')
        
        nextpage = response.xpath('//*[@class="a-last"]//@href').extract_first() # nextpage link

        self.counter = self.counter + 1

        if self.counter%250 == 0 : # to rotate proxy after every 250 rotations
            settings = initialize_VPN(save=1,area_input=['complete rotation'])
            rotate_VPN(settings)

        if str(nextpage) != 'None': # go to next page
            nextpage = "https://www.amazon.com" + nextpage
        
            yield Request(nextpage,callback=self.parseReview,dont_filter=True,meta={'item': asin})
        else:
            pass```
````